# MySQL json_table not working 2nd time the Stored proc is run

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am using json_table in 2 mysql stored procs, for both stored procs it works the first time the stored proc is run, but not after that. If I edit the proc and save it again it works again the first time, but not after. I have narrowed it down to being something to do with the json_table.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`username`@`%` PROCEDURE `sp_filter_values_add`(_dashboard_filter_id int(11))
BEGIN

insert into us_ui_dashboard_filter_values (dashboard_filter_id,  
                    section_id, 
                    section_item_id, 
                    filter_value, 
                    filter_value_text )
        
        select  dt.dashboard_filter_id, 
                x1.section_id, 
                x1.section_item_id, 
                x1.filter_value, 
                x1.filter_value_text
        from    us_ui_dashboard_filter dt,
            json_table( dt.filter_json, '$[*]' columns (
                section_id int(11) PATH '$.section_id',
                section_item_id int(11) PATH '$.section_item_id',
                filter_value int(11) PATH '$.filter_value',
                filter_value_text int(11) PATH '$.filter_value_text'
                                )
                ) x1   
        WHERE dt.dashboard_filter_id = _dashboard_filter_id; 
END
```

mysql version   8.0.12
Workbench 8.0.23

There is no problem with either of stored procs when they run the first time around the data returned is correct. The value gets returned as null after the first run, and there is no error. Not sure what else to try or even how to find a work-around.

The same code works fine repeatedly in the query windows.

Comment: Have you tried using prepared statements inside your stored procedure?

Comment: It might be this bug: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=97097.  But you will have to upgrade to 8.018 (or newer) to see if that solves it.

Comment: @Luuk - I will try an upgrade when possible, and report back.